# Issues with d3 zoomable map

Tags: d3.js

I'm having an issue with a d3 zoomable map.

I'm loading the map from a previously built topojson file with a `departments`object (the areas in the map) and a `maternidades`object (a few points in the map, initially rendered with crosses).

I'm using `d3.behavior.zoom` to implement the zoom behaviour, and I want it to be able to zoom using the mouse wheel and pan with drag. It works just fine with the map itself (the areas). However, the points in the map get shifted instantly to a wrong location at any zoom event. Also, the points' path is changed from crosses to circles somehow!

You can reproduce the issue and view the code here: http://bl.ocks.org/monsieurBelbo/5033491

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<html>
<style>
.background {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.department {
    fill: #aaa;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script>

d3.json("santafe.json", function(error, theProvince) {
    var width= 960, height= 500;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
    var departments = topojson.object(theProvince, theProvince.objects.departments);

    // The projection
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(14000)
            .center([-60.951,-31.2])
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    // The path
    var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

    // Zoom behavior
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .translate(projection.translate())
            .scaleExtent([height, Infinity])
            .scale(projection.scale())
            .on("zoom", function() {
                projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale)
                map.selectAll("path.zoomable").attr("d", path);
            });


    // The map
    var map = svg.append("g")
            .classed("provinceMap", true)
            .call(zoom);

    map.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "background")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

    // Departments
    map.selectAll(".department")
            .data(departments.geometries)
            .enter().append("path")
            .classed("department", true)
            .classed("zoomable", true)
            .attr("d", path);

    // Places
    map.selectAll(".place-label")
            .data(topojson.object(theProvince, theProvince.objects.maternidades).geometries)
            .enter().append("path")
            .classed("place", true)
            .classed("zoomable", true)
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross"))
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates.reverse()) + ")"; });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @enjalot 's suggestion, the issue was solved by re-translating the places on the zoom behaviour. Just add:

```
map.selectAll(".place").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates) + ")"; });
```

to the zoom behavior. Check out a working version here: http://tributary.io/inlet/5095947

Comment: In the line `projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale)`, you're translating and scaling the `projection`; in the line `map.selectAll("path.zoomable").attr("d", path)` you're redrawing every path with class `zoomable` according to those new coordinates.  The crosses themselves are paths with class `zoomable`, which is why you're losing them.

Comment: Yeah, but if I only redraw the departments in the map (`map.selectAll("path.department").attr("d", path)`) the crosses stay in place, but they don't scale and translate with the map zooming. What could I do @seb?